# Determine if the following sets with the given operations are groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For the first three I just want to confirm if my answers are correct. Hence I will state if it is or isn't a group. If it isn't a group I will state what property it fails. The problem I do seek assistance is number 4.

**Definition:** A group G is a set with an operation *, where * is any given operation, on G such that $\ldots$

- Closure: $\forall x,y$ $x*y \in G$
- Associative: $\forall x,y,z$ $x*(y*z) \in G$
- Identity: $\exists e \in G$ such that $e*x=x*e=x$
- Inverse: $\forall x \in G$, $\exists x^{-1}$ such that $x*x^{-1}=x^{-1}*x=e$

**Problem:**

1. ($\mathbb{Z}$,-) isn't a group since it fails the identity property.
2. $G=\{9n|n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ w.r.t. multiplication isn't a group since it fails the identity property.
3. $G=\{z \in \mathbb{C} | |z|=1 \}$ w.r.t. multiplication is a group.
4. (G, $\cdot$) where $G=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ and $\cdot$ is defined by the table:

\begin{array}{|a|b|c|d|e|f|}
\hline
\cdot & a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
a & a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
b & b & d & f & a & c & e \\ \hline
c & c & f & d & e & a & b \\ \hline
d & d & a & e & c & d & a \\ \hline
e & e & c & a & d & b & f \\ \hline
f & f & e & b & a & f & c \\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}

The closure property is satisfied because we can see that in the Cayley Table that any multiplication of 2 elements of G still returns an element in G.

Since the closure property is satisfied through a little bit of work we can also see that (G, $\cdot$) has the associative property.

From the table we see that a is the identity element of G because the multiplication of a and any other element in G will always return the other element.

**MY PROBLEM AREA:** Inverse Property
We need to show that $\forall x \in G$, $\exists x^{-1} \in G$ such that $x*x^{-1}=x^{-1}*x=e=a$ (from the previous property). Let $x \in G$. We need to find $x^{-1}$ such that the statement above is true. From the table, provided, we see

1. $a \cdot a =a$
2. $d \cdot b =a$
3. $e \cdot c =a$
4. $b \cdot d =a$
5. $c \cdot e =a$
6. $d \cdot f =a$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Your argument for the first one is not correct. $0$ is the identity (but it fails something else). I am not sure what you mean by the last one. You are done.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft O can't be the identity element for the first one. If so then we have $0-x=x-0=x$ and we know that $-x \neq x$ for every x.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, you are right.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft No problem. Can you check 2 and 3 to see if they are correct?

Comment: They seem correct to me. Also +1 for effort :)

Comment: Those are correct, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In number $4$ we have $da=d$ and $de=d$. Now in a group, $d^{-1}$ exists, and it follows $a=e$ (from $da=d=de$), a contradiction. Hence it is not a group.

Comment: Which must mean that the operation is not in fact associative, since then the existence of the identity and inverses would have implied the uniqueness.

Comment: So should I correct my associative argument or I can just write down that explanation later on in my proof?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Either would be a correct argument, though since this seems to be very introductory, they probably expect you to find a place where associativity breaks.

Comment: Well this is a graduate level course. Thank you for all your help.